# JQuery issue. Turning divs transparent on mouse hover

Tags: jquery

I've recently been learning some JQuery and I've been trying different things out. https://gist.github.com/LewisSharpe96/d1d7f6180274b29d6b9d I tried to create a series of boxes which would turn transparent when the mouse is hovered over them, then return to solid black once the mouse leaves. I can't quite figure out why the JQuery isn't working.

Comment: There is no `mouseEnter/mouseLeave` methods in jQuery... Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: What does happen when you hover your mouse over one of the boxes? Do they just stay solid black?

Comment: Yeah, they would stay solid black.

Answer (score 5):

No need for jQuery or javascript here; you can do this in CSS alone:

```
.box {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
    opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y0nsh7ht/)

Also note in your Gist that you aren't closing your `td` elements correctly.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please add transition backward compatibility info.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I mean css transition doesn't work for old browsers. I think you should give the detailed info to OP. By the way sorry for my English.